# Dispatch isn't routing internal queue requests properly

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, module, dispatch

I have a process a user can launch which inserts a bunch of items into a queue. This queue sends a request to the worker's url `/pipeline/foo` and the handler takes it from there.

The handler that consumes items coming into `/pipeline/foo` is on a separate module `module-pipeline`.

The issue is that in production `dispatch.yaml` doesn't seem to dispatch the internal requests made by the queue to the right module. However, if I manually send a request to the URL (as a user inserting the URL in the browser), it seems to dispatch me to the right module...

**dispatch.yaml**

```
application: my-app

dispatch:
  - url: "*/pipeline/*"
    module: module-pipeline
```

**load-queue.py**

```
# does some things before...

for url in urls_to_load:
    task = taskqueue.Task(url='/pipeline/foo', params={'id': url.key.id()})
    queue.add(task)
```

This works fine on the dev_appserver however in production when the queue sends the request to `pipeline/foo`its processed by the default module (returning a 404 as it's not implemented there), whereas if I send the same request manually through my browser (GET request), it's processed by `module-pipeline`

Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use parameter `target` when defining the queue in `queue.yaml` instead of routing defined in `dispatch.yaml`.

Target parameter

> A string naming a module/version, a frontend version, or a backend, on which to execute all of the tasks enqueued onto this queue.

The module (or frontend or backend) and version in which the handler runs is determined by:

- The target or header keyword arguments in your call to the Task() constructor.
- The target directive in the queue.yaml file.